# Load file into Azure DB with MSSQLConnection

Tags: jdbc, talend, mssql-jdbc

I just want to load some files into a Azure DB.
I am using the "Microsoft SQL Server" DB Type for the connection.

The problem is that when I insert like more than 10.000 rows, I have sometimes (90% of the time) an error:

```
Exception in component tMSSqlOutput_5
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: I/O Error: Connection reset
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:1091)
    at dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2.tFileInputDelimited_5Process(extractGC_child2.java:28852)
    at dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2.tFileList_6Process(extractGC_child2.java:32386)
    at dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2.tFileList_5Process(extractGC_child2.java:31540)
    at dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2.tMSSqlRow_1Process(extractGC_child2.java:30657)
    at dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2.tLoop_2Process(extractGC_child2.java:30440)
    at dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2.tFileList_4Process(extractGC_child2.java:29664)
    at dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2.tJava_3Process(extractGC_child2.java:34020)
    at dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2.tMSSqlInput_1Process(extractGC_child2.java:33593)
    at dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2.tFTPConnection_2Process(extractGC_child2.java:33154)
[FATAL]: dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2 - tMSSqlOutput_5 I/O Error: Connection reset
[FATAL]: dev_storch.extractgc_child2_0_1.extractGC_child2 - tMSSqlRow_7 Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
```

But when the volume of data inserted is lower, I don't receive any error.

My configuration looks like this:

**tMSSQLConnection**. Then I have some components to load files from a folder and load it inside a table.
The error comes at the **tMSSQLOutput**.
The following of the job are logs filling.

[image]

I tried to change the Batch size, to not use a DBConnection, but doesn't work.

I tried with a Generic JDBC component and it seems to work everytime. But I don't want to use the generic JDBC components because on the ouptut components, we can not choose the colume DB type (but maybe someone know how is it possible):

MSSQL:
[image]

Generic JDBC:
[image]

Thank you in advance...

Comment: What do you put in the field "action on Data" ?

Comment: How many Primary key do you have ?

Comment: I don't have any primary key. And in the field  "Action on Data", I put "Insert."

Comment: Have specified an "identity field" ?

Comment: no identity field nor identity insert.

Answer (score 0):

here one solution maybe your :

- Be aware that the batch size must be lower than or equal to the limit of parameter markers authorized by the JDBC driver (generally 2000) divided by the number of columns.

Comment: I have tried a lot of different Batch size, even just 1, but still the same result.